# Why do some browsers declare an opener object when there isn't one?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera

```
typeof(opener)
```

Yields "object" in all browsers but IE, though the object is null. IE only does it when one has actually used a window.open or similar method. I'd hate to think it, but is IE the only browser doing this right?

Comment: Why are you looking at the type?  Why not just look at the value?  `if (opener)`.  Of what concern is the type?

Comment: I'm just wondering why the object has been declared in the 1st place.

Comment: What does IE give for `window.hasOwnProperty('opener')` on a "normal" window (one not opened from js)? `undefined`?

Comment: @Serhiy - because `window.opener` is a valid property on the window object that should always exist as a property.  It may or may not have a non-null value assigned to it.

Comment: @bfavaretto false in either case

Comment: Even if it *was* openened from js? Interesting! What about `Window.prototype.hasOwnProperty('opener')`? (sorry, I'm on a mac).

Comment: @bfavaretto true in both cases now

Comment: @bfavaretto: FWIW, that'll be an unsafe test. The placement of properties on `window` often happen in varying positions in the prototype chain.

Comment: @thesystem I have a guess it's related to that, but I'll have to do some tests. Unfortunately, I can't do that right now, will have to revisit the issue later. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Why do some browsers declare an opener object when there isn't one?"*

In JavaScript, `typeof null === "object"`

Instead of `typeof`, use a direct `===` comparison.

```
opener === null; // true
```

If IE is giving you `undefined`, then use `==` to test for both.

```
opener == null; // true if null or undefined
```

Comment: Though true, I'm not sure that this is really related to what the OP asked. The question isn't "why does `typeof null` return `"object"`, it is "why do non-IE browsers return `null` at all in this case?" when IE doesn't. (OP doesn't say what IE does, but I assume it gives `undefined`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think it's directly related. OP is assuming that an object is unnecessarily (or incorrectly) created.

Comment: OP is wondering why the object is not undefined when a window has no opener.

Comment: @Serhiy: Read the title. OP is asking why some browsers declare an opener object when there isn't one. The answer is that they don't, and the test is flawed. The browsers declare a global variable with the `null` primitive value, but it so happens that `null`, which is not an object, returns `"object"` as a result of `typeof`. So `typeof` alone is not use for testing.

Comment: @thesystem Serhy and the OP are the same person! :P!

Comment: @bfavaretto: So odd for OP to refer to himself in the third person. :P Either way, the answer is the same.

Comment: OK, so now that you've thoroughly explained why `null` isn't really an object despite the result of `typeof null`, why doesn't IE set `opener` to `null` the way other browsers do? I think that is what Serhiy is more interested in, given the confirming comment above...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Seems like a moot question. That's what they do, and so to deal with that situation, one can test for `null` or `undefined`. Seems to me that OP is asking why there's an object when none should exist. The answer is that there isn't one, but proper testing is needed. From above: *"OP is wondering why the object is not undefined..."*

Comment: Yes, I agree that ultimately the answer doesn't really matter because browsers will do what they do and we just have to cope.

Comment: I'm coping :), I just wanted to know why I had to. Thanks @thesystem for all the details.

Comment: @Serhiy: You're welcome. You're certainly not the first to be confused by the result `null` from `typeof`. There's a long history of browser incompatibilities. Today's browsers are more compatible than ever, but still a few bumps.

Answer (score 0):

- `window.opener` is null.
- `null` is one of the primitive types which results in object with `typeof`.

Console output Chrome:

```
> window.opener
    null
> typeof null
    "object"
> typeof window.opener
    "object"
```

Console output IE9:

```
>> window.opener 
>> typeof window.opener 
"undefined"
```

So looks like Chrome/Firefox initializes it to null and IE does not defined it to start out. But when you do a truthy check it does not matter since null and undefined will evaluate to false.

Comment: `typeof null` is `"object"`, but `null` is not actually an object.

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer does a lot of things differently than other browsers. This is just one small example.

Good, cross-platform, JavaScript will need to have many instances of If-then-else branches (or as an alternative try-catch) to deal with these differences.

Comment: An easy way to test is to look at Navigator.appName